# converting from byte[] to string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting from byte[] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309003/converting-from-byte-to-string)

How to convert from byte[] to string when we are importing a excel .?

Comment: Byte array as in strings or byte array as in a raw excel document?

Comment: What is the `byte[]`? are you, for example, expecting it to be text? And if so, from what encoding? Or is it a non-text source, and you want hex/base-64/what?

Answer (score 4):

```
string myString =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
```

Comment: How do you know it is UTF-8? Or even text?

Answer (score 1):

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(yourbytearray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] b = new byte[100];
string ascii_string = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b); // For ascii string
string uni_string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b); // For Unicode String
```

Answer (score 0):

That's be the Encoding namespaces.

For example this method takes a byte array and returns a string

```
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```